# Python search for string values within dictionary and return key and value if found

Tags: python, pandas, string, dictionary

I've started over and edited my question to be more clear. I know I am just slightly missing something, but just need a little guidance with completing a solution as I'm not able to find a post to answer this.

I would like to search dictionary values for existence of multiple strings and print key and value if exists.

Here is a sample dictionary if `print(d)`

```
{0: array(['flag','weather','brown','bag'],dtype=object), 1: array(['wave','frown','happy','flag'],dtype=object)}
```

I would like search for these strings -

```
match = ['flag','frown']
```

So something like this that I have found for a single search value

```
def matchingKeys(dictionary, searchString):
    return [key for key,val in dictionary.items() if any(searchString in s for s in val)]
matchingKeys(d,'frown')
```

Where the output is then `[1]` but I would like to search multiple strings like this, but the output isn't quite working.

```
{key:s for s in match for key,val in d.items() if any(s in val for s in match)}
```

The current output is here even though `frown` only exists in `[1]`

```
{0 : 'frown',1:'frown'}
```

And this brings in every value of the key if a match is found, not just the match

```
{key:val for key,val in d.items() if any(s in val for s in match)}
```

The actual output I would like to have is -

```
{0:'flag',1:'flag','frown'}
```

Comment: What exactly are you using to display the dictionary in that first example? That's not how `dict`s normally look.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. The "dictionary" you show is not valid syntax and is not minimal. Will you show a small example dictionary that uses valid syntax?

Comment: I also have no idea what you mean by searching "within the col1 value... Where col is a dataframe column." If you actually have a DataFrame then a) you should explicitly say that you are using Pandas and tag [pandas]; b) that *isn't a dictionary*, so I don't have a clear description of the problem here.

Comment: ```type(d[0])``` returns a ```pandas.core.frame``` but ```type(d)``` returns ```dict``` so it is a unique case

Comment: Please show: an *exact* example input; the *exact desired* result; the *exact* code you've actually tried before (reduced to the part relevant to the problem); and *exactly what happened* when you tried that code (and how that is different from what you want).

Comment: "type(d[0]) returns a pandas.core.frame but type(d) returns dict so it is a unique case" This means that you have a dictionary where at least one of the keys (`0`) is an integer, and the corresponding value is a `DataFrame` instance. Okay, now I can make sense of the output you showed. Please try to start over and describe the problem more clearly.

Comment: Ok thank you, I have tried to be more clear

Comment: MCVE means show code to construct the dictionary from a toy dataframe(s) constructed just for the question.

Comment: I've started over and edited my question to be more clear

Comment: You can post your answer as an answer to your own question

Comment: ah well now that it's be re-opened i can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out successfully

```
dict((key, [x for x in value if x in match]) for key,value in d.items())
```